# Can msmtp rewrite addresses?

Tags: debian, etc, gmail, msmtp

I am trying to get all my system emails to be forwarded to my gmail address, using `msmtp 1.8.3` and `/etc/aliases` on debian. It works, but I get errors from gmail.

When I email `root` (via `echo "hello world" | mail -s "forward me" root`), I obtain 2 emails in the inbox of the gmail address:

1. The expected forwarded email
2. The following message from `mailer-daemon@googlemail.com`

```
Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to root@backupbox because the domain backupbox couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.
The response was:

DNS Error: 5452395 DNS type 'mx' lookup of backupbox responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: backupbox
```

Obviously, it is not surprising that gmail cannot reach `root@backupbox`, since from their perspective, `backupbox` is not a fully qualified domain name. I am however surprised, because I aliased all my system addresses to my gmail address.

Here is my msmtp configuration:

```
# /etc/msmtprc
defaults
port 587
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
from me@gmail.com
auth on
user me
password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
account default : gmail
aliases /etc/aliases
```

Here are my system aliases

```
# /etc/aliases
default: me+backupbox@gmail.com
```

How do I make sure that only the first email reaches me? For example, can `msmtp` rewrite `root@backupbox` as `me@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `msmtp` can rewrite addresses exactly like this. I have a similar setup on my machine and

```
echo 'a test email' | msmtp root
```

works as expected.

Perhaps the issue is with the `+` symbol. Maybe it needs to be escaped in some way. I'd suggest trying it without a `+` to test. Although obviously as your question is from 2019 you've probably found another way by now!